# Square wave generator won't work

Tags: generator, wave, square

I'm trying to generate a square wave at 21kHz (+13V,0V) using this schematic:

[image: Schematic]

I used formulas and [this website](http://www.learningaboutelectronics.com/Articles/Op-amp-oscillator-calculator.php) to find the correct values for my components but it doesn't seem to work on Simetrix.

Do you see any problem?

Comment: If you start with IC=0 all nodes being being  0V is a valid. Solution but not stable in the real world due to noise. Try setting a different IC, does this help?

Comment: Simetrix examples include at least one square wave generator that works!

Comment: This is just a canned comment to let you know that what you're trying to build from discrete analog components (possibly incorporating Opamps and/or NE555) is a digital control problem and thus can easily and with lower parts count be solved with a microcontroller with really minimal firmware to write.

Comment: Hi Gragon. Another canned comment - ground symbols should *never* point anywhere but down. Rotate the op-amp, flip it, whatever it takes - convention is very important for readability. Here is a short [reference](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/28255/69058) on how to draw great schematics.

Answer (score 7):

Your positive feedback attempts to move the non-inverting input above and below ground. This would work with a dual supply system - ie negative rail below ground.

In a single supply system you need to provide hysteresis above and below some intermediate voltage - this may be Vcc/2 or some other value to allow for eg the fact that input common mode range is typically ground to Vcc-1.5V.

As Jasen notes - the resistor values are on the small side.
The LM2904 will source and sink 10+ mA but it is best to limit I/O current to usefully less than I_out_max.

In this case try eg at the non-inverting input

- Remove R2
- Add 15k to V+
- Add 10k to ground.
- Change R1 to 10K.
- Increase R3 and decrease C1 - or reduce the hysteresis range (smaller R1) to increase frequency.

That should provide an OK starting point for playing.

[LM2904 data sheet](https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/datasheet/c8/d5/4d/58/88/9d/44/9f/CD00000535.pdf/files/CD00000535.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.CD00000535.pdf)

Comment: also use higher resistors, the LM2904 can only do a few milliamps,

Comment: @Jasen Yes. Probably around 10 mA but quite a lot less is desirable. I've added related comment in my answer.

Comment: @Peter Karisen - your answer was OK, but (as you know) only covered part of the options. Leaving it there would have done no harm.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon Thank you for you answer. At first it wasn't working but then i reduced R1 to reduce the hysteresis range and it worked! But i only have spikes and not a square  wave, where does that could come from ?

Comment: The square wave comes from the values of the components being balanced correctly to provide the necessary [hysteresis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hysteresis).

Comment: @Gragon You have not advised what R & C values you have used or what the frequency of operation is. We are unable to start to guess what you are doing or seeing - and updated circuit and functional description would give us some chance of being helpful. The cap max V value MUST remain below (Vcc-1.5V) and preferably lower yet. That's why I made the suggested bias resistors assymetrical.  Increasing R1 will reduce the hysteresis voltage swing - which increases frequency but may be a good idea. || What component values are you now using? | What is the frequency of operation?

Answer (score 0):

Let's first look at the output divider pair, \$R_1\$ and \$R_2\$, you provided. This takes the opamp output and divides it in half. (We are assuming you aren't over-loading the output's current compliance for the moment.) If you assume the opamp is a perfect rail-to-rail output then the output may either be \$V_\text{CC}\$ or else \$0\:\text{V}\$. So that means that \$0\:\text{V} \le V_{\text{IN}_+}\le \frac{V_\text{CC}}{2}\$. But clearly, given \$R_3\$ and \$C_1\$, it follows that under all circumstances \$0\:\text{V} \le V_{\text{IN}_-}\le V_\text{CC}\$.

Note the fact that both ranges have \$0\:\text{V}\$, inclusive? Not so good.

What you want is that the range for \$V_{\text{IN}_-}\$ to completely envelope, clearly and unambiguously, the range for \$V_{\text{IN}_+}\$. Let's leave the basic concept presented by \$R_3\$ and \$C_1\$, so that we continue to allow \$0\:\text{V} \le V_{\text{IN}_-}\le V_\text{CC}\$. But we must now restrict the range of \$V_{\text{IN}_+}\$.

It's really convenient to set a range such that \$\frac{1}{3}V_\text{CC} \le V_{\text{IN}_+}\le \frac{2}{3}V_\text{CC}\$. Then you may keep your resistor values all the same; for both \$R_1\$ and \$R_2\$, as well as a new one I'm adding to your circuit. (But I'd recommend increasing their values, somewhat -- perhaps to \$10\:\text{k}\Omega\$ to lighten the load on the opamp's output.) And then simply add one resistor from \$V_{\text{IN}_+}\$ to \$V_\text{CC}\$, using the exact same value for it that you use for \$R_1\$ and \$R_2\$.

If you sit down with the simple RC exponential decay equation and work out the timing required to go from \$\frac{1}{3}V_\text{CC}\$ to \$\frac{2}{3}V_\text{CC}\$ you will have half of the total cycle time. And you can use that equation to solve for a value for \$R_3\$ given some value for \$C_1\$, pretty easily. In that way, you can achieve your \$21\:\text{kHz}\$ value.

You should be able to write that equation very quickly in this fashion:

$$\frac13 V_\text{CC}+\left(V_\text{CC}-\frac13 V_\text{CC}\right)\cdot e^{^-\frac{t}{R_3\:C_1}}=\frac23 V_\text{CC}$$

That reads as, "The capacitor voltage starting at \$t=0\$ is one-third of \$V_\text{CC}\$. To that, we add the charging rate which is driven by the difference between \$V_\text{CC}\$ and the starting point voltage, that difference then times the exponential decay rate over time. We want this result to reach two-thirds of \$V_\text{CC}\$." Or something like that, anyway.

You can work out that half the time is \$t=\frac1{2\:f}\$ where \$f=21\:\text{kHz}\$. Just drop in your value for \$C_1\$ and you should be able to compute a value for \$R_3\$.

It's really no more complex than that.